# Scala - what is this map + case syntax?

Tags: scala

I can't seem to find further information on this language feature where you can put a `case` inside a `map` like this:

```
   val sVersion = CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion)
      .map { case (major:Long, minor: Long) => s"_$major.$minor" } getOrElse ""
```

I've been starting to use this syntax, but what is it called and where can I find more information on it?

Comment: Is just another form of the lambda syntax to creating functions, you can think of it as sugar for `x => x match { ... }`

Answer (score 5):

> I've been starting to use this syntax, but what is it called […]

It is officially called a *Pattern Matching Anonymous Function*. The Scala community also sometimes refers to it as a *Partial Function Literal*.

> […] and where can I find more information on it?

The ultimate source of truth for everything in the Scala Programming Language is the [*Scala Language Specification* (aka *SLS*)](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/). You will note that I have linked to version 2.13 of the spec – unfortunately, a single consolidated spec for Scala 3 has not been published yet.

See [Scala Language Specification 8.5 *Pattern Matching Anonymous Functions*](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#pattern-matching-anonymous-functions) for all the gory details. Simply put, the expression

```scala
{
  case p1 => e1
  case p2 => e2
  // …
  case pn => en
}
```

is equivalent to

```scala
(x1: S1, x2: S2, /* … */, xn: Sn) => (x1, x2, /* … */, xn) match {
  case p1 => e1
  case p2 => e2
  // …
  case pn => en
}
```

provided that the result type is [SAM-convertible](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/06-expressions.html#sam-conversion) to [`FunctionN[S1, S2, /* … */, Sn, R]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/Function1.html), or as a special case [`PartialFunction1[S1, R]`](https://scala-lang.org/api/3.x/scala/PartialFunction.html) (which is where the name *Partial Function Literal* comes from.)

In Scala 3, there is a new feature which can make this code even more concise: For a very long time, the Scala Designers wanted to unify *Tuples* and *Argument Lists*. In other words, they wanted to make it so that methods in Scala only ever take one argument, and that argument is a tuple. Unfortunately, it turned out that a) this massively breaks backwards-compatibility and b) massively breaks platform interoperability.

Now, Scala 3 was an opportunity to ignore problem a), but you cannot ignore problem b) since one of the major design goals of Scala is to have seamless, tight, good, performant integration with the underlying host platform (e.g. .NET in the case of the now-abandoned Scala.NET, the ECMASCript / HTML5 / DOM / WebAPI platform in the case of Scala.js, the native Operating System in the case of Scala-native, or the Java platform (JRE, JDK, JVM, J2SE, J2EE, Java, Kotlin, Clojure, etc.) in the case of Scala-JVM).

However, the Scala designers managed to find a compromise, where arguments and tuples are not the same thing, but parameters can be easily converted to tuples and tuples can be easily converted to arguments.

This is called [*Parameter Untupling*](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling-spec.html), and it basically means that a function of type `FunctionN[S1, S2, /* … */, Sn, R]` can be automatically converted to a function of type `Function1[(S1, S2, /* … */, Sn), R]` which is syntactic sugar for `Function1[TupleN[S1, S2, /* … */, Sn], R]`.

Simply put,

```scala
(p1: S1, p2: S2, /* … */, pn: Sn) => e: R
```

can automatically be converted to

```scala
(x: (S1, S2, /* … */, Sn)) => {
  val p1: S1 = x._1
  val p2: S2 = x._2
  // …
  val pn: Sn = x._n

  e
}
```

With this, your code would look like:

```scala
val sVersion = CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion)
  .map { (major: Long, minor: Long) => s"_$major.$minor" } getOrElse ""
```

---

Note: unfortunately, there is no comprehensive specification of Scala 3 yet. There is a partial [Language Reference](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/overview.html), which however only describes differences to Scala 2. So, you typically have to bounce back and forth between the SLS and the Scala 3 docs.

Answer (score 4):

In Scala 2, it's called  `pattern-matching decomposition`

see: https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/other-new-features/parameter-untupling.html

in Scala 3, you can just

```scala
val sVersion = CrossVersion.partialVersion(scalaVersion)
      .map { (major:Long, minor: Long) => s"_$major.$minor" } getOrElse ""
```

Answer (score 0):

This is usually called "destructuring" or "destructuring bind" (ex: in Clojure https://clojure.org/guides/destructuring). Scala uses pattern matching to achieve this.

In your example, you use shortened pattern matching to destructure the `Option` which contains the version. You could also skip the explicit `Long` type declaration.

Good reads on this topic:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/programming-scala-2nd/9781491950135/ch04.html
https://docs.scala-lang.org/cheatsheets/index.html